# How to Convert List<String[]> to Comma Separated String without " " in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, filereader, filewriter, csv-write-stream

I'm trying to remove fist line from the CSV file after reading it. Code is working properly but it's adding "" to my data when it's rewriting. 
for an example:

- before write to csv file: 100,COMRADE,CAMPBELL
- after write to csv file: "100","COMRADE","CAMPBELL"

  Here is the code.

========================================================================

```
public void deleteLineFromCsv() throws IOException {
        List<PatientsTabData> list = new ArrayList<>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("src/main/resources/patients.csv")));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null) {
            String[] split = line.split(",");
            list.add(new PatientsTabData().patientId(Integer.parseInt(split[0])).patName(split[1]).patLastName(split[2]));
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        list.remove(0);
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/main/resources/patients.csv")));
        List<String[]> newlist = list.stream().map(item -> new String[]
                {String.valueOf(item.getPatientId()), item.getPatName(), item.getPatLastName()})
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        writer.writeAll(newlist);
        writer.close();
    }
```

> Library:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: please add the library name of csv writer.

Comment: added to the question

Comment: If your requirement is really just that: removing the first line from a file, then I would wouldnt use a csv reader/writer here. Just read the file line by line with a normal buffered reader, and omit writing the first line.

Comment: @GhostCat Any example please?

Comment: Please step back. I really dont understand what exactly you intend to achieve. I mean: what is the actual purpose of your code? What exactly goes in and is expected to happen? What data needs to be in the file, and "in memory" after the method ran?

Comment: I have a patient.csv file and I'm using this file as a @DataProvider. First I'm reading first row (ex: 1, name, lastname) from the csv file and after test I'm removing the used line from the csv file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another constructor when creating your writer. Change

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/main/resources/patients.csv")));
```

to

```
CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(new File("src/main/resources/patients.csv")),',',CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the way to convert List to comma Seprated Single String.

```
List<String[]> oldList= . . . ;
String requiredString = oldList
.stream()
    .map(Arrays::asList)
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: what about this part (item -> new String[]
                {String.valueOf(item.getPatientId()), item.getPatName(), item.getPatLastName()}) ?

Comment: @SanjX see my updated answer.. If you have `List<String[]>` then it converts in String comma seprated without "". perform above operation on your newList.

Comment: it won't work like that. Because I'm using write.writeAll();
writeAll
(java.util.List<java.lang.String[]>)
in CSVWriter cannot be applied
to
(java.lang.String)

Comment: @SanjX what is your title. Read again. I answered it according to your title.

Comment: then how this person understood it correct :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55222066/7758011
never mind thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV writer is writing each element as string in the csv file. This can be by design in library as it will keep any comma in your data in the string and later will not add extra column if your data has comma as well.

```
"name","class","house, street, city","value"
```

See the documentation of your library and check if it provides the option to not treat every element as string.

But my opinion is to keep the strings in quotes to avoid data descripency during reads.